# Can't activate the event click

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Why can't I activate the event of click on this function (can't alert Done!)?

```
$("#content_tc p").click(function()
{
        alert("Done!");
    operacao = "4";
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/tc.php",
        data:
        { 
            operacao: "4"
        },
        dataType: "html"
    })

    .done(function(msg)
    {
        $("#content_tc").append(msg);
    })

    .fail(function()
    {
        $("#content_tc").text("Error"); 
    });
});
```

The code above is a file named tc.js

In the html page, where the script is called (p in `div id="content_tc"` is where I need to click):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="Content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="central">
        <div id="content_tc"><p>a</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(document).ready(function() {...})` or shorter form `$(function() {...});` to make sure all of your DOM elements are loaded properly before executing your javacript code:

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

If your elements are dynamically created, you can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
$('body').on('click', '#content_tc p', function() {

});
```

Comment: Check your script tag calls to make sure the javascript makes it into the page. Also check to make sure jquery loads first then your script. You can check out the fiddle of your code. It works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/qw5ph/

Comment: When I try to use event delegation, like:

$(document).ready(function()
{
 
 $('body').on('click', '$("#content_tc p")', function(){
 });
});

I get de following message: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $("content_tc p")

Do you know why? Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing `#` in your selector `#content_tc`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrongly. The message was: Sytax error, unreconized expression: $("#content_tc p")

Comment: Sorry, you just need `#content_tc p` instead of `$("#content_tc p")`. You can check fiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/pdR4C/1/